# How to show that a language {w|ww^R in A} is regular, A being regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

Been working on my homework and I've been stuck on a question for over a week now. Not really asking for a solution but if someone could point me towards the right direction that would be great, as I have literally no idea of how to go about this. A previous question asked us to show that for any DFA that accepts A, we can create a NFA that accepts {w<sup>R</sup> | w in A}, which was pretty easy (just reverse the DFA).

This question asks: Show that if A is a regular language, then so is {w|ww<sup>R</sup> in A}, where w<sup>R</sup> is the reverse of the string w.

I know that if I have two regular expressions, then their concatenation is also a regular expression, that's simple. But this asks me to show that the first-half of *some* of the strings in A is a regular expression. No idea how to show that this is true. It's not even intuitive to me that this *is* true, except that the question implies it is.

Anyone got any idea of where to start about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to study [If $L$ is a regular language then so is $\sqrt L=\{w\mid ww∈L\}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41281/if-l-is-a-regular-language-then-so-is-sqrtl-www-in-l).

The solution is to simulate the DFA in parallel with itself, from both sides of the string. For each letter one step forward (for $w$) and one step backward (for $w^R$). If the forward state reading $w$ reaches the same state as the backward simulation, both parts joined form a computation on $ww^R$.

Comment: To make this explicit: use non-determinism *heavily*. You can determinise it away after, if you want.