# Prove regularity of $L$ implies regularity of $\widetilde{L} := \{xy \mid xxy \in L\}$

Tags: regular-languages

Let $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$. For every language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ we denote
$\widetilde{L} := \{xy \mid xxy\in L\}$. Prove that if $L$ is regular, then so is $\widetilde{L}$.
I tried playing around with the automaton for $L$ and extending it in ways, but I always keep adding unwanted words to the new language and therefore get a language actually bigger than $\widetilde{L}$. I also thought about somehow employing the Myhill-Nerode theorem and the finite equivalence classes of $\approx_L$, but I couldn't rerally figure out an useful way of doing it... Any help is welcome!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41281/755

Comment: Wow, okay, that was much heavier than expected...